# Ansible Ad-Hoc command - raw module not working on Cisco IOS devices

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, ansible-tower

trying to use Ad Hoc commands on both my Cisco ios Router and Switch with the ***-m raw*** Module. But getting the following error instead.

**$ansible -i inventory_file02.ini netgrp -m raw -a "show version" -u abdo -K**

**Error====**

```
BECOME password: 
R1 | FAILED | rc=127 >>
/bin/sh: 1: show: not found
non-zero return code
SW1 | FAILED | rc=127 >>
/bin/sh: 1: show: not found
non-zero return code
```

**Inventory file=====**

```
R1 ansible_host=192.168.20.1
SW1 ansible_host=192.168.10.2

[netgrp]
R1
SW1
```

**group_vars/netgrp.yml===**

```
---
ansible_connection: network_cli
ansible_network_os: ios
ansible_user: abdo
absible_password: kali/abdo
ansible_become: yes
ansible_become_method: enable
ansible_ssh_pass: kali/abdo
```

**$ ansible -i inventory_file02.ini netgrp -m raw -a "show version" -u abdo -kK -vvv**

```
ansible [core 2.12.6]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/kali/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/kali/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.4 (main, Mar 24 2022, 13:07:27) [GCC 11.2.0]
  jinja version = 3.0.3
  libyaml = True
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password: 
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]: 
host_list declined parsing /home/kali/ansible_play01/net_play02/inventory_file02.ini as it did not pass its verify_file() method                                                                                                        
script declined parsing /home/kali/ansible_play01/net_play02/inventory_file02.ini as it did not pass its verify_file() method                                                                                                           
auto declined parsing /home/kali/ansible_play01/net_play02/inventory_file02.ini as it did not pass its verify_file() method                                                                                                             
yaml declined parsing /home/kali/ansible_play01/net_play02/inventory_file02.ini as it did not pass its verify_file() method                                                                                                             
Parsed /home/kali/ansible_play01/net_play02/inventory_file02.ini inventory source with ini plugin
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.
META: ran handlers
redirecting (type: connection) ansible.builtin.network_cli to ansible.netcommon.network_cli
redirecting (type: connection) ansible.builtin.network_cli to ansible.netcommon.network_cli
redirecting (type: terminal) ansible.builtin.ios to cisco.ios.ios
redirecting (type: cliconf) ansible.builtin.ios to cisco.ios.ios
redirecting (type: terminal) ansible.builtin.ios to cisco.ios.ios
redirecting (type: become) ansible.builtin.enable to ansible.netcommon.enable
redirecting (type: cliconf) ansible.builtin.ios to cisco.ios.ios
redirecting (type: become) ansible.builtin.enable to ansible.netcommon.enable
<192.168.10.2> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: kali
<192.168.10.2> EXEC show version
<192.168.20.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: kali
<192.168.20.1> EXEC show version
SW1 | FAILED | rc=127 >>
/bin/sh: 1: show: not found
non-zero return code
R1 | FAILED | rc=127 >>
/bin/sh: 1: show: not found
non-zero return code
```

Answer (score 1):

`ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION` is not a -vvv message I would expect, the local connection plugin just execs commands on localhost. Note the /bin/sh shell, not something found on IOS. For network_cli, I would expect `LOCAL` to instead be `PARAMIKO` or `LIBSSH`.  (Years ago network devices used local connection plugin plus module parameters, but this is long obsolete by actual connection plugins.)

[Network troubleshooting guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/network_debug_troubleshooting.html) suggests it could be just `ESTABLISH CONNECTION`. But that could be outdated; modern connection plugins by convention include their name.

So your connection variables are consistent with how to [configure connections to IOS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_ios.html), but they may not be applying correctly. Which you put in group_vars, which is a fine choice. However, I think defining hosts `R1` and `SW1` twice is causing problems.

Keeping your ini format inventory, delete the hosts outside the group but keep the host variables:

```ini
[netgrp]
R1 ansible_host=192.168.20.1
SW1 ansible_host=192.168.10.2
```

Vars can be defined almost anywhere. Try defining these in other places, to see what works, and what feels natural. For example, there is syntax for defining [group level vars in inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-many-machines-group-variables) which could replace your use of group_vars for connection details.

```ini
[netgrp:vars]
ansible_connection=network_cli
ansible_network_os=ios
ansible_user=abdo
ansible_become_method=enable
```

Comment: I actually did try putting my variables in different places, and I did just as you said.. But unfortunately with no result!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  The problem is that if ansible_connection=network_cli is set in a vars file, the show command is executed on the local workstation (control node,) not on the router.

To override that, I passed that variable on the command line: `ansible -e ansible_connection=paramiko ...`.  ansible_connection=ssh might also work, but I found paramiko more forgiving of the ssh protocol versions found on older ios devices.